# Full Screen, Immersive Mode, disable left swipe navigation bar

Tags: android

Is it possible while in full screen immersive mode to disable the left swipe gesture opening the main navigation bar, so that it can only be opened swiping from the top? When developing full screen games its pretty annoying having to design so heavily around preventing users accidentally opening it.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Sorry just to clarify i'm talking about a horizontally locked, full screen game in immersive mode, disabling the left swipe gesture that makes the main android navigation bar/notification bars appear, i'm hoping there is a way to only let this be opened via swiping from the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

to lock your DrawerLayout so it won't be able to open with gestures. And unlock it with:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Comment: Doesn't works for me. Anyone has some example about this? I have a player with a controller, and the horizontal swipe must be banished for show the inmersive menu... but must to work if you made a vertical swipe.